# How to make socket connection from Android Emulator to another pc which is on the same lan

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator

I am very new to Android. Our lan is working in class C IP (192.168.1.x series).
I need to establish socket connection between android emulator(Server) and java eclipse (eclipse-java-juno-SR1) which is acting like a client. As I got a information from  "http://developer.android.com" website every Android emulator having 10.0.2.15 (Class A IP) by default. But our LAN is working in Class C.

"PC-1" which is using for Android Emulator is having 192.168.1.50 IP, and
the another one "PC-2" which is using for Eclipse-Java is having 192.168.1.55.
This is the setup which I have.

My work is, When I send a string command (through socket) from Android emulator(runing on PC-1) to Java program(runing on PC-2) then that Java program should send continuous jpg photo to Android emulator through socket.

I tried lot but when I try to work with sockets installed apk application is closing by this error:  "Unfortunately, Activity name> is closing"

Please help me out in this... 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your Application have the

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

in your Manifest - File ?

You can either insert the above line into the manifest xml,

or you can go to "permissions" add "uses permission" and then add the "Internet" one.

My Emulator has no problems opening a Webview to the internet with this permission,
and I can even access my router in my network through the browser in the emulator, which is on some 192.168...  address.

Kind Regards and a Happy New Year,

karlheinz

Comment: Thank you and wish u the same karlheinz. Yes I have added Internet permission. But still my android application is closing in emulator. Do u want me to upload my project code...?

Comment: What does your "Logcat" say why the application is closing ?

Comment: ya thanks, i got it how to fix from Logcat.... , Its from thread problem, main thread is closing due to more task doing on that, so i have created separate thread for socket.